# How to make the most of having an Abathur on your team?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

There is a question on [how to play Abathur correctly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/169587/what-kinds-of-things-can-i-do-to-play-abathur-better), which is surely warranted given his unique mechanics. However, my question is more about how to be a good team mate for an Abathur player.

In [this recent Heroes of the Dorm match](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJNVcjWvY4w) the casters allude frequently to the fact that the other four players on an Abathur team should change their play style, but I'm unsure how I should be doing that, not in the least because low rank pubs are different from more professional matches.

Specifically, I'm wondering:

- Should Abathur typically be left ot solo a lane, or does he require some kind of support?
- What are the things to watch for on your own character given that Abathur can use abilities to enhance others?
- How do you need to compensate / account for an Abathur on your team for map objectives such as treasure chests and skulls?
- Is it necessary to check on Abathur's build and adjust your play style accordingly?

But, in short: **how can you be a good team mate for Abathur** in public matches?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should Abathur typically be left ot solo a lane, or does he require some kind of support?

Abathur's trait, locusts, are most effective when no one's countering his lane. In the beginning, help a solo laner against another solo laner for pushing. During objective time, switch to an empty lane (top lane in Blackheart's Bay when chests are spawned for example). Abathur pushes best when he's ignored. Therefore, an Abathur should relocate as much as he can for the optimal pushing and avoiding hunters such as Nova, Zeratul and Tyrande(owl).

> What are the things to watch for on your own character given that Abathur can use abilities to enhance others?

Abathur has 2 major builds I'd say: [teamfight build](http://www.heroesnexus.com/talent-calculator/2-abathur#IOMA5ONOTMFOPACAA) and backdoor pushing build. When Abathur goes teamfight build:

- After level 4, **your attack speed is increased 25%.** This means, you should keep auto attacking on certain situations with Illidan/Thrall or simply you can win almost every 1v1 when Abathurs symbiote is on you. So stay alert.
- When Abathur uses symbiote on you, be ready to engage as you are a 1.75 person now with the Abathur on you. His Q and W deals significant damage with talent upgrades <sub>(See lvl 1 and lvl 7 talents)</sub>.
- After level 20, if Abathur takes **Hivemind** talent and goes symbiote on 2 targets. If symbiote is on you, try to stay close to the other symbiote host, so the second symbiote is not cancelled. This way, Abathur will have double the damage potential, and 2 of the teammates will have 25% increased attack speed. Pretty rad.

> How do you need to compensate / account for an Abathur on your team for map objectives such as treasure chests and skulls?

In general, you should not fully commit to team fights when you have an Abathur in the team. You should always be more careful as you have only 4 players to target in a team fight, so it is easier to get nuked. Positioning is very important when Abathur is in your team. **Play safer**, try not to engage 5v5 too early and you'll not feel Abathur's body absence.

> Is it necessary to check on Abathur's build and adjust your play style accordingly?

If Abathur player doesn't communicate, that is **exactly** what you should do. If he goes backdoor build, you have to be even more careful on team fights. Adapt a general hit and run strategy that game and let Abathur work his magic back door.

> But, in short: how can you be a good team mate for Abathur in public matches?

Just don't engage like you are 5v5. Always communicate with teammates. Use pings on yourself if you need help from Abathur.

Answer (score 5):

- Abathur should never solo a lane. He should be left near a solo laner so that his little bugs help push that lane against another solo laner.
- If voice communication is not an option, you should use pings when Abathur is going to clone you so that you can get ready to go all out in teamfights. It's really up to you as the reciever of the buffs to decide on how to use them well. If you need some assistance pushing lanes, just tell your Abathur to buff you next.
- The actual Abathur hero can be used for scouting, but that's pretty much it. He lacks any real fighting skill on his own and will lose in any 1v1. You need to use his buffs and his ultimate to turn 2v2's into 2v3's. It can *really* catch the other team off guard. They will always think they have the advantage when in reality you will always be +1 in non-5v5 teamfights.
- Any Abathur team will most likely avoid fighting 5v4 unless Abathur has his ult up. Again, use pings and chat to coordinate these.
- Abathur should be always communicating on what talents he is taking and when his ult is up. It's on the Abathur player to step up in communication when it is needed.
- **Communicate = Being a Good Mate!**